# My PHP's hash_algos() function no longer works

Tags: php, html, algorithm, hash

I'm not entirely sure what version of PHP, but I'm thinking it's in the 5.2 (Relatively new installtion of XAMPP). There was a certain site I built and it relied heavily on the php function hash_algos() to populate a drop down list, but it seems as of late that the hash_algos() returns absolutely nothing. Also, using windows, if XAMPP didn't give it away.

The site used to work, but doesn't anymore, and I'm not sure why, I haven't changed anything in the code. Here's the part of the site that isn't working

```
<select name="method" id="method">
<?
foreach(hash_algos() as $m)
{
echo "<option value=\"".$m."\">".$m."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: PHP 5.2 is definitely not relatively new.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: http://php.net/hash_algos

Comment: "The site doesn't work" - isn't helpful. Haven't you forgotten to turn on your server?

Comment: @OffLuffy, as the manual says, you need to have `PECL hash >= 1.1`. Do you have it?

Comment: @zerkms The server is running, the site is parsing PHP well enough, and it returns a PHP error when trying to run hash() because the hash_algos() isn't returning the algorithm name, so assumedly since I can connect to the site, Apache is running, and the error tells me PHP is active.

Comment: @OffLuffy: "and it returns a PHP error" --- right, and now we need to guess the exact error message?

Comment: @zerkms Not a total guess. You can figure what it would say if you tried hash() with a null value for the algorithm argument.
"Warning:  hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: null"

Comment: @OffLuffy: so when you call `hash_algos()` it returns `Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: null`? I don't see anything about `hash()` function in your question, only `hash_algos()`.

Comment: @zerkms hash_algos() is used to populate a drop down list which is used to select an algorithm type which is then passed to the hash() funciton. I have no problem with the hash() function, but hash_algos() isn't producing the algo array and then hash() gets passed a null.

Comment: @OffLuffy: "isn't producing the algo array"  --- so it returns `null`? Look at the comments please and see, that we spent 15 minutes and you still haven't provided **DETAILS** of what's going wrong. Programming is a science around precise things and facts, not about guesses and doubts.

Comment: @zerkms Either that or an empty array. In short, it's not producing a value. Even using print_r(hash_algos()), it doesn't print any visible characters.

Comment: @OffLuffy: "Either that or an empty array. In short, it's not producing a value" --- not helpful at all. Use `var_dump()`. If it doesn't return anything - see error logs.

Comment: @zerkms As it happens, <? no longer works. Didn't seem to count the <? unless it was <?php so the hash_algos() wasn't being parsed as PHP at all. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @OffLuffy: "so the hash_algos() wasn't being parsed" - incorrect. It was parsed. Look at error logs.

Comment: @zerkms Only the hash() error showed up in the logs. Checked that. But that code was on a separate page and it used <?php ?> hash_algos() was being treated as normal html.

Comment: @OffLuffy: Well, I can repeat that once again: `var_dump(hash_algos());` + see to the logs. If there is nothing in your logs - there is a chance logging is turned off

Comment: @zerkms jeezus man, it was plain text. var_dump(hash_algos()) when viewed in Chrome's HTML viewer was shown just as that. My server didn't seem to think that <? ?> delimited PHP, so though it was some sort of <> html tag. The logging is on, it showed all the hash() errors in the log, the one I told you. Problem is solved now simply by changing <? to <?php.

Comment: @OffLuffy: ok. Now you see - that asking question without investigation is not efficient? Your original question has **nothing** to do with the problem. It's just completely irrelevant piece of code.

Comment: @zerkms Well if I knew the problem was that to begin with, I wouldn't have needed the question at all. If you're so intent on being anal about it, have the question deleted. Had someone been familiar with the error, one might have known to check the real error in the process of troubleshooting. No point in this rabble now, problem solved, over and done with.

Comment: OffLuffy: Feel free to delete your own question since it no longer makes sense now that you've discovered the solution. Don't mind zerkms, he's always like that (and don't take requests for clarification personally, we're really trying to help).

Comment: @OffLuffy: if you looked at the html response (it's the first thing you are supposed to do) - you would see that there is php code not parsed there.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: I'm always like what? ;-) Like trying to teach people of how to ask questions? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: You just come off as angry and sometimes insulting, but trust me - I understand why ;)

Comment: @Wesley Murch: as a justification I could say that in the culture I'm from my words don't sound roughly at all. But the thing is - it can be treated so by another part of the world... So, trying to teach myself to be a bit more polite (and I'd say I've made huge progress for the last couple of years) )))

Comment: Soft skills are overstated it seems. Ofc, you get that high up and soft skills aren't as necessary. I get it as well at any rate, PHP isn't my forte, just a side project. Had I expected to see any PHP relevant data in plain HTML, surely would've checked that before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the Hash PECL package enabled.

This question may be of use to you: [How to switch hash_algos() on ? I'm with Php 5.2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946638/how-to-switch-hash-algos-on-im-with-php-5-2-11)

Edit: Since you're on Windows, you'll likely have to compile the "Hash" package yourself. It appears to be [available on the PECL website but is no longer maintained](http://pecl.php.net/package/hash).

To compile from source, PHP has a [step by step guide](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

After you've compiled the DLL or got ahold of one, you need to add it to your php.ini file.

You'll need to add a line like the following:

```
extension=php_hash.dll
```

More information is available on [PHP's Windows site](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php).

Comment: I saw that in the process of searching for this problem, although I can't figure out how to enable or install PECL on windows. That thread seems geared towards Linux.

Comment: On second thought, I didn't see the php.ini comment prior, I'll try finding something there.

Comment: You need to have the DLL for the Hash package. I'm trying to look for it now but no luck yet. You can probably compile it from source though. http://pecl.php.net/package/hash seems to have the source

Comment: Yeah, saw the source in the tar for the linux package, although I'm not right sure how to compile from source, thanks though.

Comment: I updated my answer but check if you have an "ext" or "extensions" folder where PHP is installed. It might already be compiled.

Comment: I'm using the ext folder and php.ini is pointed to the right one, but I haven't tried adding the extension= line yet. I don't think I even saw php_hash.dll when I was looking through them. I'll double check for other names, thanks for the help.

Comment: Found the problem. PHP wasn't wanting to consider code in <? ?>, had to use <?php ?> instead, now it seems to be working fine. Thanks though XD

Answer (score 0):

you forget

```
<?php ?>
```

syntax so

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <select name="method" id="method">
            <?php
                foreach(hash_algos() as $m)
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"".$m."\">".$m."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

start server and run.